# How do I iterate an IGrouping<T> Interface?

Tags: c#, linq

Ive got ths really annoying issue I have grouped a set of data and I cant get to the data within the group. I can get to the key bit not the data..

I have a load of data that is in the form

```
Data.Period = x
Data.Adjustment = y
```

I perform a GroupBy

```
var groupedData = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Period new {x.Period});
```

This brings back (according to linq) my hierarchical data which is starting to look how I want it. Id like to iterate through the contents but cant...How do I do this? and how do I...

Work how to get to the Data.Adjustment without using a projection. And I dont want to project yet because I have to perform another grouping....help! :-)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface inherits `IEnumerable<TElement>`:

```
foreach (var group in groupedData)
{
    var groupKey = group.Key;
    foreach (var groupedItem in group)
        DoSomethingWith(groupKey, groupedItem);
}
```

I note that you will be better off using this for your query, however:

```
var groupedData = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Period);
```

rather than this:

```
var groupedData = Data.GroupBy(x => new {x.Period});
```

If, for example, you wanted to average the adjustments, you could do this:

```
foreach (var group in groupedData)
    Console.WriteLine("Period: {0}; average adjustment: {1}", group.Key, group.Average(i => i.Adjustment));
```

Comment: Hi how do I perform a query on the group in the final foreach statement in your code? How do I cast it into a n Igroup?

Comment: @Exitos you don't need to cast it to an `IGroup`; it already *is* an `IGroup`.  See edited answer for an example.

Comment: Then how can I query the group after your first foreach statement? thanks btw

Comment: Wait a minute I got it I just use a lamda and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Exitos The example I added shows how to query the group for the average of its members' `Adjustment` property.  If you describe the kind of query you'd like to do, I will post an example that more closely resembles your requirement.

Comment: Anyone know if IGrouping is able to be safely iterated multiple times without tolisting?

Comment: @user15716642 it's impossible to say without knowing what the underlying concrete types are and without knowing what you mean by "safe."

Comment: Generally, IEnumerables shouldn't be iterated over multiple times because you have no clue if someone is using it with a query that needs to be generated each time or if it's a persisted icollection. I was wondering if the group would also perform all the same operations to re-group entries. E.g., if I have entries grouped and I do multiple selections of properties from a specific `IGroup`, will each `myGroupedItems.Select(x)` call have to go and re-group all of the entries again? I feel like this is a simpler question that I can't word quite right, so I'll probably post a separate answer lol

Comment: @user15716642 well whether the class implementing the group caches its items is an implementation detail.  After all, arrays and `List<T>`s are IEnumerables, and it's perfectly fine to iterate them multiple times.  You can easily test whether multiple iterations of the grouping cause multiple iterations of the underlying IEnumerable, just be alert to the possibility that the behavior might change in a different version of the framework.

Answer (score 16):

Each element of a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is an `IEnumerable<TElement>` that you can iterate over to get the data that has a common `TKey`:

```
var groups = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Period);
foreach(var group in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine("Period: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach(var item in group) {
        Console.WriteLine("Adjustment: {0}", item.Adjustment);
    }
}
```

So in the above, `groups` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TPeriod, TAdjustment>>` where `TPeriod` is the type of `Period` (you didn't tell us) and `TAdjustment` is the type of `Adjustment`. Then, `group` is an object that implements `IEnumerable<TAdjustment>` (but it also has a `Key` property so that you can get the key. Finally, `item` is a `TAdjustment`, and for each `group`, all the `item` that come from iterating over that `group` have the same key.

Answer (score 13):

Though maybe obvious for others one can also use:

```
var groups = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Period);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
   List<Data> dataListByPeriod = group.ToList();
   //use this list
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just use `foreach`:

```
foreach(var group in groupedData)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Period: {0}", group.Key);
   foreach(var item in group)
      Console.WriteLine("   Adjustment: {0}", item.Adjustment);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code as well.

```
var groupedData = Data.GroupBy(x => x.Period);

foreach (var group in groupedData) {
    var gr = group.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("Period: {0}", gr.Period);
    Console.WriteLine("Adjustment: {0}", gr.Adjustment);
}
```