# EditorTemplates Where or Groupby on Questionnaire

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates, editortemplates

At the moment, I have a working prototype for a questionnaire with multiple questions and each question having multiple choices for an answer.  Everything displays and saves great.  However, I now would like to group the question/answers into 'sections' on my Edit view.  I have tried a couple different methods but nothing seems to work correctly.  The working code without sections are as follows:

**Edit View** Progress Report:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportAnswers, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportAnswers)
    </div>
</div>
```

**ReportAnswers.cshtml** (editor template)

```
<h3>
    Question
</h3>

<p>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Question.QuestionText)
</p>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportID)

@foreach (var answer in Model.Question.PossibleAnswers)
{
    var id = string.Format("answer-{0}", answer.AnswerID);
    <p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportAnswerID)

        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnswerID, answer.AnswerID, new { id = id })
        <label for="@id">@answer.AnswerText</label>
    </p>
}
```

**EditController**:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProgressReport progressReport)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(progressReport).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (ReportAnswer answer in progressReport.ReportAnswers)
            {
                        if (answer.QuestionID != null && answer.AnswerID != null)
                        {
                            db.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }                   

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ClientID = new SelectList(db.Clients, "ClientID", "ID", progressReport.ClientID);
        return View(progressReport);
    }
```

Data structure is Sections -> Questions -> Answers
I then have a ProgressReport table that has QuestionID and AnswerID

I have attempted to Groupby within the view, but then unsure how to call the Editortemplate correctly.  In fact, I was able to use it, but the result was not as expected.  that code is:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.ReportAnswers.GroupBy(s => s.Question.SectionID))
```

Thanks!

**Data Structure Snippet:**
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to develop a solution...proper or not..Don't know...but it does work.  Feel free to critique.  I welcome it.  :)

ProgressReportViewModel:

```
public class ProgressReportViewModel
{
    public int ReportID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReportDateSubmitted {get; set;}
    public List<ReportAnswer>[] ReportAnswerSection { get; set; }
    public string[] SectionHeadings { get; set; }
    public string[] SectionDescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

EditController:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var viewModel = new ProgressReportViewModel();

       //  Get the section in order of defined display order
        var questionsection = (from s in db.QuestionSections
                                orderby s.SectionDisplayOrder
                                select new{
                                    s.SectionName,
                                    s.SectionDesc
                                });

        viewModel.SectionHeadings = new string[11];
        viewModel.SectionDescriptions = new string[11];
        viewModel.ReportAnswerSection = new List<ReportAnswer>[11];

        int i = 0;
        foreach(var section in questionsection)
        {
            //  Loop through sections and get the name, desc and the questions/answers
            viewModel.SectionHeadings[i] = section.SectionName.ToString();
            viewModel.SectionDescriptions[i] =   section.SectionDesc;
            viewModel.ReportAnswerSection[i] = db.ReportAnswers.Where(q => q.Question.SectionID == i+1 && q.ReportID == id).Include(s => s.Question.QuestionSection).OrderBy(q => q.Question.DisplayOrder).ToList();
            i=i+1;
        }

        var report = (from r in db.ProgressReports
                      where r.ReportID == id
                      select new
                      {
                          r.ReportID,
                          r.ReportDateSubmitted,
                          r.ClientID
                      }).SingleOrDefault();
        viewModel.ReportID = report.ReportID;
        viewModel.ReportDateSubmitted = report.ReportDateSubmitted ?? DateTime.MinValue;


        return View(viewModel);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProgressReportViewModel progressReport)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProgressReport PR = db.ProgressReports.Where(x => x.ReportID == progressReport.ReportID).SingleOrDefault();


            //db.ProgressReports.Attach(progressReport);

            db.Entry(PR).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++ )
            {
                foreach (ReportAnswer answer in progressReport.ReportAnswerSection[i]) //.ReportAnswers)
                {
                    SaveAnswers(answer);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(progressReport);
    }
```

ReportAnswers Editor Template

```
<h3>
Question
</h3>

<p>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Question.QuestionText)
</p>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportID)

@foreach (var answer in Model.Question.PossibleAnswers)
{
var id = string.Format("answer-{0}", answer.AnswerID);
<p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportAnswerID)

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AnswerID, answer.AnswerID, new { id = id })
    <label for="@id">@answer.AnswerText</label>
</p>
}
```

Edit View:

```
@for(var i = 0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SectionHeadings[i]) </h4>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SectionDescriptions[i]) </p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportAnswerSection[i])
    }
```

I chose to do these arrays because there is one section at least I need to intercept to do something special with.  Otherwise all other sections are typical.
This seems to work but as stated, I welcome any criticisms anyone may have.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

You will be better of creating view models that represents the data you want to display in the view

```cs
public class ReportVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  // other properties or Report for display/editing
  public List<SectionVM> Sections { get; set; }
}
public class SectionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // other properties or Report for display/editing
  public List<QuestionVM> Questions{ get; set; }
}
public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; }
  public List<Answer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

The in the controller, use your `.GroupBy()` query to build your view model and add each section and its related questions/answers

Then add an `EditorTempate` for `SectionVM`

```cs
@model SectionVM
@Html.HiddenFor(m = > m.ID)
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</h2>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Questions) // uses an EditorTemplate for QuestionVM (i.e. as per your current ReportAnswers template
```

and in the main view

```cs
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sections)
```

Comment: So are you saying I should abandon my current use of the existing editor template I currently have?  Also, Can I use the {get; set;} in a viewmodel with a db first application?  I guess I always thought that was for the model itself with a model first app?  Or maybe that is a dumb question?

Comment: In addition, I guess I wasnt thinking of doing the .GroupBy() in the controller...I guess i can do that?

Comment: You usage of `EditorTemplates` is good (and is easier to read than multiple nested `for` loops). But in order to represent what you want to display in the view, you really need to use a view model rather than trying to use your data models in the view. In your case your have a Report, which contains a collection of Sections, with each Section containing a collection of Questions, with each Question containing a collection of possible Answers

Comment: Okay.  Good to know for the future but I guess with this complexity I will attempt to move forward with implementing view models...back to the drawing board....

Comment: Your view should never contain complex logic such as linq queries. Near impossible to test and debug. In any case your would need nested `foreach` loops to access `ReportAnswers` -  [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723627/how-do-i-iterate-an-igroupingt-interface) for an example. But this usage would mean that your could only ever display the `SectionID` property (because that's the `Key` property) and I suspect you probably want to also display a Name/Title property for each section

Comment: I am looking over the view models you provided and I just want to be sure I understand all correctly and that I do not need to modify them.  I have updated my initial question with a quick screenshot of my abridged data structure.  Would the VMs be okay with that.

Comment: No time now, but I will have a look later today (note the naming I used may be a little different because I did not know your database structure)

Comment: No problem.  I understand.  I will continue attempting to resolve this in the meantime. :)  Thank you so very much.  I really appreciate your time!

Comment: After looking at this off and on throughout the day, I am at a loss.  I do think I need to switch around the Viewmodels according to my data structure, but I have attempted several things and just not sure how to 'make it all work'.  Controller, Viewmodels and editor templates...  In the process of reading up a bit more on Viewmodels in hopes I can solve the issues here.

Comment: @Voyagr12, Sorry I only got around to this a few moments ago. Based on your database structure, I don't think you have any choice but to use view models for each type if you want to group your questions/answers by Section. And in anycase view models are always the best approach. I am a bit puzzled why `ReportAnswer` has field `AnswerText` when `PossibleAnswers` also includes `AnswerText`?

Comment: Yes, Trying to go the Viewmodel route...Just not sure how to get there.  :)

Comment: And ReportAnswer contains AnswerText and AnswerID because some questions are multiple choice where others are a text based answer.  Possible Answers table is really only used for those questions with multiple choice.  I have all this working from the previous assistance you gave but now nothing works that I try when I introduce sections. :)

Comment: I think to start with, you just need to initialize a new instance of `ReportVM` and manually fill in some values to test it in the view. Based on your database structure, the queries necessary to populate the view model look like they may be rather complex (and the subject of another question)

Comment: I think I may be at the point where I need pay for help.  Do you do pay consulting?  :)

Comment: Actually, I just thought of something that may make this easier for me.  My sections would not be changing really much at all...maybe never.  So...perhaps I can create separate list in my VM for each section of the Questions that would be in that section.  Then still call my existing editor template  that I am currently calling.  Or something like this anyways...Just a thought at the moment.